# About error TRUE/FALSE needed when displaying list in R

Tags: r

I met a pretty strange error in R. When I tried to display a list returned by `lapply`, the following error message was showed:

```
Error in if (n <= 1L || lenl[n] <= width) n else max(1L, which.max(lenl >  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

The if... in the error message was not written by me, I think it is some inner function of R.
The code I wrote looks like the following (`flags` is a dataframe)
The first statement was executed successfully, the error only appeared when I tried to display unique_vals by running the second statement.
Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

I have tried to change the font of the console to the smallest, as well as use `na.omit()` to delete the missing values in the list, but none of them worked. I am extremely confused about why simply displaying a list will incur such as error, which I have never encountered before.

```
unique_vals<-lapply(flags,unique)
unique_vals
```

Comment: Tomori, I suggest there might be something about `flags` that is either (a) not what you think it is, or (b) is not appropriate for `unique`. As RonakShah suggested, without knowing what the data looks like, we cannot help. Please provide an unambiguous sample of your data, perhaps with `dput(head(flags))`, though please verify that `lapply(head(flags), unique)` also produces the error; if not, find some sample of the data that produces the error without flooding the page with otherwise unneeded data. (And then edit your question and add the data in a code block.)

Comment: When I get an error message that makes no sense in the context of *my code*, I often look within the R source code and see if I can find insight. In this case, I went to wch's [github clone of r-source](https://github.com/wch/r-source), searched for the literal test `"(n <= 1L || lenl[n] <= width)"` (quotes included), and found a single instance [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/ce662f3a0bfef14e19a560a58b0baff25032e561/src/library/base/R/factor.R#L175). This to me suggests that your data has `factor`s in it and something is wrong with those factors. `dput` is now even more necessary.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3358272/r2evans I'm fascinated by the ability to search the R source code. I went to https://github.com/wch/r-source and searched there and elsewhere on how to search the code and so far, no luck. Anything you could add to help, please?